# Magento2: How to override Catalog Product Mass Delete file?

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalog, massaction

I want to override Catalog Product Mass Delete file in Magento2

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete.php

My Code:

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
            <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete" type="Amy\AdminProductDeletion\Controller\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\MassDelete" />
</config>
```

Controller file:

> app/code/Amy/AdminProductDeletion/Controller/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/MassDelete.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Amy\AdminProductDeletion\Controller\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;


class MassDelete extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product
{
    /**
     * Massactions filter
     *
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;


    protected $transportBuilder;


    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Builder $productBuilder
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Builder $productBuilder,
        Filter $filter,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository = null
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        // echo "Amy";
        // die;
        $productDeleted = 0;
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {

            $productid = $product->getId();
            $productsku = $product->getSku();
          //  $productname = $product->getName();
            print_r($productsku);
            print_r($productid);
            //print_r($productname);
            //die;


            $objectManager      = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
            $sellerId = $objectManager->create(
                'Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Product'
            )->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                  'mageproduct_id',
                ['eq' => $productid]
            )
            ->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['eq' => 1]
            )
            ->addFieldToSelect('seller_id');
            $sellerIdFilter =  $sellerId->getdata();

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($sellerIdFilter);
            echo "</pre>";
            //die;



            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
            $customerModel = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($sellerIdFilter);
            $customerEmail = $customerModel->getEmail();
            $customerfirstName = $customerModel->getFirstname();
            $customerlastName = $customerModel->getLastname();
            print_r($customerEmail);
            print_r($customerfirstName);
            print_r($customerlastName);
            //die;



            $consumer_email = "sample@gmail.com";
            $requestData['mail_subj'] = "Product deleted by Admin";
            $requestData['hello_txt'] = "Hello " . $customerfirstName;
            $requestData['prodid'] = $productid;
            $requestData['prodsku'] = $productsku;
            //$requestData['prodname'] = $prodname;
            $requestData['message'] = "This is to inform you that your Product has been Deleted by Admin.";
            $postObj = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObj->setData($requestData);

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('delete_product')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObj])
                ->setFrom(['name' => "Product Deletion", 'email' => $consumer_email])
                ->addTo($customerEmail)
                ->getTransport();

            $transport->sendMessage();


            $this->productRepository->delete($product);
            $productDeleted++;
        }

        if ($productDeleted) {
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $productDeleted)
            );
        }

        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT)->setPath('catalog/*/index');
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to move di.xml file in to vendor/module/etc/adminhtml

Comment: okay will move it.

Comment: I am getting error while compiling

Comment: which error ???

Comment: Class Amy\AdminProductDeletion\Controller\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Builder does not exist                                                                                                               
  Class Amy\AdminProductDeletion\Controller\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor generation error:

Comment: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permissio  
  n is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then y  
  ou must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

Comment: try to follow all step

Comment: I added step in answer

Comment: Okay will check it.

Comment: Try extending the Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete.php file or the Action file instead of the \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product file.

Answer (score 1):

In Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml -

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete" type="Amy\AdminProductDeletion\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete" />
```

And in __construct replace Builder by \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder like-

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository = null
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository
            ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $productBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Preference :-**

> **Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete" type="Amy\AdminProductDeletion\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete" />
```

**After This Follow this Steps :-**

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f

php bin/magento cache:flush

chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/static generated/
```

Comment: I have tried this. It is not working.

Comment: attached your code

Comment: Attached my code, could you please check it.